Get the product variant that matches closest to the input value for related length
In Craft and Commerce 4 I want to select the variants from a specific product (already selected), but the product variants contain a related field called fixingLength and the related entries live in a section called lengths have a numeric field called mm.
I want to choose the closest variant available based on the  variants fixingLength (related field) that matches a value that is entered.
E.G 37
I am unsure how I can filter the variants by the fixingLength size (37).
I can do it like so with hard coded ID's
 {% set variant = craft.variants()
  .productId(4247)
  .fixingLength(106)
  .one() %}

Where 106 = 37mm as a entry.
But then I need to find the closest match is say the user enters a value where there is no exact variant. (e.g  35mm)
I have managed to get so far with the following code;
{% set input = '33' %}
{% set fixinglengths = craft.entries.section('lengths').orderBy(expression("ABS((field_mm) - :inputNumber)  ASC", {inputNumber: input|integer})) %}
{% set variant = craft.variants()
         .productId(4247)
         .fixingLength(fixinglengths.one().id)
         .one() %}

{{ variant.title }}

This works if there is a variant that matches exactly the input (length).
However, because this code is looking up the lengths first then relating it tot he variants, it doesn`t work by getting the closest variant available.
Is this at all possible?
Thanks
Terry
